# ClusterIP service not distributing request to two Deployments with same labels

Tags: kubernetes

Beginner Kubernetes Learner here.

I have two deployments with same label and a service object which I want to be able to forward requests to both pods 1 in each deployment. The only difference is that the container running in the pod is different in both environment. The difference is just a text that is displayed in the browser and nothing else is changed between the two images. I have verified that the container on it self runs fine.

The issue I am facing is that when I run a service on top of these pods and port forward on service port, It only forward requests to one pod always.

**The Deployment File**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: cloudnatived/demo:hello
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8888
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: raheel-demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: raheel-demo
          image: raheelwp/mydemo
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8888
```

**Service File**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8888
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: ClusterIP
```

Below are the some results from `kubectl` commands which tells that both the pods are registered with the service (Endpoints)

```
❯ k get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
demo-6cf4f66696-9kfqv          1/1     Running   0          7m13s
raheel-demo-77c6fc76d6-dqrzg   1/1     Running   0          10m

❯ k get deploy
NAME          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
demo          1/1     1            1           24m
raheel-demo   1/1     1            1           24m


❯ k describe svc demo
Name:              demo
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=demo
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=demo
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.108.229.204
IPs:               10.108.229.204
Port:              <unset>  8888/TCP
TargetPort:        8888/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.37:8888,10.1.0.38:8888
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

If I kill the pod that the service is currently forwarding requests to, then I get the following error

```
❯ k port-forward service/demo 9999:8888
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9999 -> 8888
Forwarding from [::1]:9999 -> 8888
Handling connection for 9999
Handling connection for 9999
E0405 00:42:35.730661   91452 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 9999 -> 8888: error forwarding port 8888 to pod 0f71c84a492c2175a9084508ef2c31ac49fbd6c6af2e2768270ca5e37812246d, uid : container not running (0f71c84a492c2175a9084508ef2c31ac49fbd6c6af2e2768270ca5e37812246d)
E0405 00:42:35.733850   91452 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
```

I am not sure if my understanding of Service is incorrect and it cannot forward requests to pods spanning multiple deployments, or there is a error in my configuration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you do a ``kubectl get service -o wide`` and ``kubectl get pods -o wide`` and update the question with the results?

Comment: How are you trying to test/access the deployments through the cluster IP? Are you pinging or curling it?